How to configure that the deletion of the dependent cascade deletes the principal (one-to-one)?
Given these entities:
public class StoredArticle
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public StoredTimePeriod TimePeriod { get; set; } = null!;
}

public class StoredTimePeriod
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public DateTime Start { get; set; }
    public DateTime End { get; set; }
}


I want that Article and TimePeriod have a one-to-one relationship. As I understood TimePeriod is the principal and Article is the dependent, because it's having the foreign key pointing to TimePeriod
This is how I setup their relationship:
modelBuilder.Entity<StoredArticle>(entity =>
        {
            
            entity
                .HasOne(e => e.TimePeriod)
                .WithOne()
                .HasForeignKey<StoredArticle>("TimePeriodId")
                .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Cascade);
        });

With this setup, following happens:

When removing the Article, the TimePeriod remains in the database
When removing the TimePeriod, the Article is removed too (cascade)

But I want it the other way around. And I don't wan't to add ArticleId to TimePeriod, because TimePeriod is used also in other classes.

I found a simple solution for this constraint. It's basically EF's Owned Entity Types
It'll add the StoredTimePeriod columns directly to the StoredArticle Table. But it can also be configured to use separate tables.
